# Benefits of splitting out Domain Models, BAL, and Interfaces into separate projects rather just merged into one project called Core

Tags: c#, architecture, repository-pattern, n-tier-architecture

I currently use the following architecture which is only 3 layers:

```
*TestProj.Api
*TestProj.Core
     -Models
           Customer.cs
     -Services
          CustomerService.cs
     -Interfaces
          -Repositories
               ICustomerRepository.cs
          -Services
               ICustomerService.cs    
*TestProj.Data
      CustomerRepository.cs
      BaseRepository.cs
```

I figure it is a good thing to put the Domain Models and every single Interface in the Core project. I also figured why not put the Services which contain all of the Business Logic inside of Core since business logic is technically part of the domain and could even be inside of the Domain Models if not going with an anemic domain model approach.

I am very comfortable with this architecture, however I would like to know if I could gain from getting rid of core and creating projects: TestProj.Services and TestProj.Domain and just put the Interfaces in the same projects as their actual classes (for example: ICustomerRepository would now be in TestProj.Data with CustomerRepository and ICustomerService would now be in TestProj.Services with CustomerService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting Question. Assuming , your Domain Models and Data models are the Same objects. To start with can i first propose the following setup

```
TestProj.Api
TestProj.Domain.Models
      -Customer.cs

TestProj.Domain.Services
      -ICustomerService.cs

TestProj.Domain.Services.Implementations
      -CustomerSerice.cs (implements, IcustomerService, Depends on ICustomerRepository)

TestProj.Data
     -ICustomerRepository.cs
     -BaseRepository.cs

TestProj.Data.EntityFramework
    -EfCustomerRepository.cs(Implements ICustomerRepository)

TestProj.Data.UsingSomeOtherORM
   -OtherOrmCustomerRepository.cs(Implements ICustomerRepository)
```

> Principles Followed are

1. Every project can reference Domain.Models , but Domain.Data does not reference another projects (to aim for)
2. Separate the Contracts (Interfaces) from the implementations.
3. Should be able to Vary Implementations/ **Invert Dependencies**

**For -**

> I would like to know if I could gain from getting rid of core and
>   creating projects

The main thing you gain is dependency inversions and a way of splitting the solutions into very tiny/Independently testable projects. Also it would be great to provide different implementations if needed, both for your Business Logic(Services) and Data layers.

Hope this Helps!